# Regex for accepting decimal numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want regex which will accept decimal numbers The decimal number like '12.12,123.23,09.90 or 2.78' i.e there should be 2 decimal places after decimal point and should accept 1,2 or 3 digits before decimal point i.e its optional for 1,2 or 3 digits before decimal point.

I've added this but not works

`var validates=/^\d+\.\d{0,3}$/;`

Comment: A bit beside the point, but If you are validating an input you could validate direclty with <input type="number" step="any" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var validates = /^\d{0,3}\.\d{1,2}$/m;
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yG4eF0/1)